# swift Dictionary with [UInt8] as value convert to json string

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I create a swift class as shown below:

```
 class Message {
    var type:String
    var content:[UInt8] = [UInt8]()
    init(type:String, content:[UInt8]) {
        self.type = type
        self.content = content
    }
func jsonAsString()->String {
    var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    for (_, attr) in mirror.children.enumerate() {
        if let property_name = attr.label as String! {
            print("property_name: \(property_name) and value:\(attr.value)")
            dict[property_name] = attr.value as? AnyObject
        }
    }
    do {
        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        return (String(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: ""))!
    } catch {
        NSLog("ERROR when parse JSON")
    }
    return ""
}
}
```

I want to call the function 'jsonAsString' to get a json string, but the property 'content' which is an uint8 array not convert correctly.
As I found a lot, some one suggest to replace

> var dict = String: AnyObject with 
>   var dict = String: Any

But this type of dictionary is not supported by the method

> NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(obj: AnyObject, options opt: NSJSONWritingOptions) throws -> NSData

Comment: You will need to convert the array to `[Int]` before you convert it to JSON

Comment: @Paulw11 I define [UInt8] array just like java byte[], if I convert it to be [Int], that will be still ok?

Comment: Because uint8 is smaller Int you can convert without any loss of data; it may not be possible to convert from Int to uint8 if you have values >255

Comment: @Paulw11 Any better way to convert a [int8] to [int]

Comment: You just have to loop though and create a new array, it may be better to use an [int] start with and use value checking where appropriate to make sure that you don't put values >255 in

Comment: @Paulw11 I will put a json string to the [Int8] array then send to the server(Java server use byte[] to receive it), so it may be that value>255.May have to loop it which a little be stupid.

Comment: That sounds pretty stupid.  Why doesn't the Java server simply accept a string? But a UInt8 can't be bigger than 255 - 8 bits, unsigned = 0-255

Comment: @Paulw11 The server now is working fine for web client and  android client, so it is impossible to change server side code.

Comment: Ok. An array of Int and an array of uint8 will behave identically in this case. You just need to use the right encoding when you convert the string to the array